# the nightwatch chrome said --ignore-certficate-errors

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to launch selenium using chrome nightwatch build, hoever on execution it says --ignore-certificate-errors. I stuck on this for a long time and can't solve this.

**My config:**

```
module.exports = {
    'test': function(browser) {
        browser
            .url("https://www.baidu.com")
            .end()
    },
}
```

**nightwatch.json:**

```
{
    "src_folders": ["tests/e2e"],
    "output_folder": "tests/e2e/reports",
    "custom_commands_path": "",
    "custom_assertions_path": "",
    "page_objects_path": "",
    "globals_path": "",

    "selenium": {
        "start_process": true,
        "server_path": "node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/2.53.1-server.jar",

        "log_path": "",
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 4444,
        "cli_args": {
            "webdriver.chrome.driver": "node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.22--chromedriver",
            "webdriver.ie.driver": "node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/iedriver/2.53.1--iedriver"
        }
    },

    "test_settings": {
        "default": {
            "launch_url": "http://localhost",
            "selenium_port": 4444,
            "selenium_host": "localhost",
            "silent": true,
            "screenshots": {
                "enabled": false,
                "path": ""
            },
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "chromeOptions": {},
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true,
                "phantomjs.binary.path": ""
            }
        },

        "chrome": {
            "desiredCapabilities": {
                "browserName": "chrome",
                "javascriptEnabled": true,
                "acceptSslCerts": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm ran out of ideas,
please help

Comment: I am having this issue too. Did you resolve this issue.